# How to fix videos that turn to white while watching them?

Tags: video

Every time I play a video (mp4, avi, etc) with Ubuntu 21.10, the video fades to white including the controllers (like play button, the time bar etc) but the audio is still working.

Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Any errors in terminal `xd-open path/to/a/video`

Comment: I cannot find the command `xd-open` and any package including it.

Comment: I'm sorry a letter was running away :D `xdg-open` is the correct command.

Comment: What app are you using to play the video?

Comment: just the built-in video player in nautilus (I just click on a file)

Comment: Try with `vlc`. But it might be with your video file .... or does it happen with any video?

Comment: @nobody thanks:) tried with that command but no error are returned on the terminal (although the video fades to white still)

Comment: @pLumo it happens with any video file

Answer (score 0):

use vlc or other players video players because built in video players lacks some codecs or check all audio video drivers configured properly.
type

```
 lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
```

to see driver info

use [this post on intel community](https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-NUCs/NUC10i5-headphones-jack-audio-not-working-with-Ubuntu-20-04/td-p/643946) or [sound Troubleshooting](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure)

Comment: you could just tell the OP that he/she can find all of the codecs in sofware center,just search for gstreamer.